# Difference between javaee api , javax-servlet-api, javaee-web-api?

Tags: jakarta-ee

What is the purpose of javaee api, javaee-web-api, javax-servlet-api ? , what would be the application for these dependencies ? is javaee api a superset of javaee-web-api?.

Answer (score 0):

servlet is a component of java-web,java-web is use Java technology to reslove some  web problems,alaway used in server-side.
--A little bit of my opinion